# How to search on site content page with operators?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, sharepoint-search, site-contents

Within my SharePoint Online site, I see how cool it is to search for document with operators, such as...

> Red NOT White

It will pull up my assets that have Red, but leave out any that also include white. Sweet!

But on the **Site Content** page, when I search for a document library or list, and want to filter out documents in the same fashion...

> Library-A NOT XYZ

...Nothing shows up for results even though I do have a document library called "Library-A".  Is there any way to *enable* search operators on the site content page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this is currently not supported. If you try to search, you will find that the search on the site content page is all list/library, and the item/file cannot be searched.

And I think the search on the site content page is not as smart as on the document search page.